# Python Shell in Emacs 24?

Tags: python, emacs, emacs24

I recently upgraded from Emacs 23 to Emacs 24. Since the upgrade, it seems that I've lost the ability to call "M-x python-shell" (!).

What happened? Does the included python mode no longer ship with this functionality?

Using Emacs 23:

```
○ /usr/local/bin/emacs -Q

Describe function: python-shell
    python-shell is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
    `python.el'.
```

Using Emacs 24:

```
○ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -Q

Describe function: python-shell [No match]
```

Comment: What about `py-shell`? That's the command in XEmacs 21.5; maybe it has changed to this name in GNU Emacs as well.

Comment: Nope, when I try to tab complete "M-x py...", I see "python-mode" as the only completion.

Comment: As you noted, if python-mode is not loaded, the py-shell function won't be available.  You can use an autoload in your .emacs instead of explicitly loading the mode `(autoload 'py-shell "python-mode" "Python shell." t)`

Comment: Do you have `(package-initialize)` after `(add-to-list 'package-archives ...)`? It looks like you need it to load the packages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287947/adding-marmalade-as-package-source / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550899/whats-the-magic-behind-the-elpa

Comment: @DanJaouen, can you please add your solution as an answer and mark it correct, or mark Shantanu's answer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems like you only solved the `python-mode` issue. As to `M-x-python-shell` you can also get this by doing `M-x-run-python`. If it says directory not found its because the the python variable is not pointing to the correct path. So do `C-h-f run-python` then it will tell you that run-python's value is python-shell-interpreter. So then point it to python.exe in your python folder.

add this to your .emacs file

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "path to python.exe")
```

Then like in emacs 23 you can do `C-c-C-c` to run a .py file.

edit-the reason i have all of this here even though you may already of known this is because i didnt realize that emacs24 changed the python value for run-python for a while and this is how i fixed it. :D